# Python: Any ideas on how to check is an element in a string is a digit or not, without using .isdigit()?

Tags: python, integer, typechecking

I am supposed to write a code for a program that will ask a user to input an integer and if the input is not an integer it will print 'try again' and if it is an integer it just quits the program. The only issue is that we are not allowed to use the `.isdigit()` method. I need to come up with a method to check if each element in a strong is a digit or not without using `.isdigit()`.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: "I need to come up with a method" - That's right. _You_ need to complete this task.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free homework plagiarism service.

Comment: You can use try except!

Comment: Wow I asked for ideas. You know, like maybe point me in the right direction or help me understand something. It is very possible to politely help a student out without giving me the answer. Very welcoming community.

Comment: You're supposed to get that from your instructor.

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question.  [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:
    input_str = raw_input('input: ')
    input_set = set(input_str)
    digit_set = set([str(digit) for digit in range(0, 10)])
    # print "isdigit: ", digit_set.issuperset(input_set)
    if digit_set.issuperset(input_set) is True:
        break
    print 'try again'
```